# Data Struture for Mapping Table in Python

Tags: python, data-structures

I need some input from more experienced devs for my data structure.

**What do I want to do?**

I am writing on a converter for a mapping table. It works, but I think there is a much nicer way to set up the structure.

Of course, the business logic should be easy to set up, but at the same time, the structure should still be readable.
Does anyone have a suggestion?

**Mapping table:**

```
System A    | 4 | 5 |5* |6x | 6x* | 6y | 6y* |  6c | 6c* | 7x | 7x* |  
System B    |   | 4 |5  |6x | 6x* | 6y | 6y* |  6c | 6c* | 7x | 7x* |
System C    |   X0  |X1 |X2 | X3  |    X4    |  X5 |    X6    | X7  |
```

There are three different grading systems (A, B, C). Each consisting of grades which are loosely comparable to each other.

> eg. *"X4"* (System C) can be converted to *"6y"* or *"6y*"* (System A)
>
> eg. *"6c"* (System B) can be converted to *"X5"* (System C)

**Current structure**

```py
mapping = {
    "name": ["System A", "System B", "System C"],
    "grade": {
        0: ["4", "", "X0"],
        1: ["5", "4", "X0"],
        2: ["5*", "5", "X1"],
        # ... and so on. 
    }
}

# the current standard is "System A"
input_system = 0

# the input is the index number for the grade
input_grade = 4

# expected output: "In system A it is 6x*."
print(f"In {mapping.name[input_system]} it is {mapping.grade[input_grade][input_system]}.")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have is a three-way mapping, which would most succinctly be represented using a list of tuples:

```
# Not clear if you want "" or None to represent the non-existent System-B
# equivalent of System-A "4"
mapping = [
    ("4", "", "X0"),
    ("5", "4", "X0"),
    ("5*", "5", "X1"),
    ...
]
```

Then you can define any of the 6 X->Y mappings in terms of the tuple list.

```
from operator import itemgetter

a_to_b = dict(map(itemgetter(0, 1), mapping))
b_to_a = dict(map(itemgetter(1, 0), mapping))
a_to_c = dict(map(itemgetter(0, 2), mapping))
c_to_a = dict(map(itemgetter(2, 0), mapping))
b_to_c = dict(map(itemgetter(1, 2), mapping))
c_to_b = dict(map(itemgetter(2, 1), mapping))
```

You can minimize the storage (not that we're using a lot to begin with) by trading O(1) conversons for O(n) lookups.

```
def convert(sys_from, sys_to, grade):
    sys_from = {"A": 0, "B": 1, "C": 2}[sys_from]
    sys_to = {"A": 0, "B": 1, "C": 2}[sys_to]

    for grade in mapping:
        if grade[sys_from] == grade:
            return grade[sys_from]
```